# colorSpace confusion in metal

Tags: rendering, textures, metal, color-space

Now I created `MTLTexture` through `textureloader` and need to reuse the object. When I use `replaceRegion`, I found that the colorSpace of the new loaded image does not match the original image. I have the following problems:

1. Should I get the colorSpace of the texture, and then convert the colorSpace of the new image to match? If yes, how I could get the colorSpace of the texture?
2. Can I specify the colorSpace I want to use when using `textureloader` to create a texture?
3. Is there any ready-made method for NSImage to get rawValue? I am currently using a function written by myself to extract the rgb component
4. What is the effect of `metalView.colorPixelFormat`? Whether I change it has no effect on the picture

I am new in swift and metal, is there any systematic learning path, thanks!

```
//create texture
self.textures = (0..<maxFrameinFlight).map { _ in
            do{
                let textureOptions: [MTKTextureLoader.Option: Any] = [
                       .generateMipmaps: NSNumber(value: false),
                       .SRGB: NSNumber(value: false)
                   ]
                return try textureLoader.newTexture(name:"pic2",
                                                    scaleFactor: metalView.window?.backingScaleFactor ?? 1.0,
                                                    bundle:nil,
                                                    options: textureOptions)

            } catch{
                fatalError("Could not load texture, error: \(error)")
            }
        }

//...

//replaceRegion
if(changeRequest){
            changeRequest = false
            let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, Int(stagingBuffer.size.width), Int(stagingBuffer.size.height))
            var data2 = imageToPixels(image: stagingBuffer)
            textures[currentFrame].replace(region: region,
                                            mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: &data2,
                                            bytesPerRow: Int(stagingBuffer.size.width) * 4)
            changeAgain = true
        }
```

Comment: `replaceRegion` doesn’t do any color management, it just copies the data

Comment: you are right, I want to pass the pixel value which owns  the same colorSpace I used in the `textureLoader`, but I failed to do that :(